# How to add multiple for example 3 images per line in a listview (Kotlin)

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, imageview

In R.layout.maskot_list (custom row for listview), there are three imageView and I tried to show something like:

```
mascot1.jpg . mascot2.jpg . mascot3.jpg
mascot4.jpg . mascot5.jpg . mascot6.jpg
etc
```

which means 3 (multiple) images per row and I have already tried the following code I have mentioned below. But it is showing the images like:

```
mascot1.jpg
mascot2.jpg
etc
```

which means only 1 image per row. So, how can I solve this problem.

```
 package jp.co.lumber_mill.toyotago.fragment
    import android.content.Context
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter
    import android.widget.ImageView
    import android.widget.ListView
    import android.widget.TextView
    import jp.co.lumber_mill.toyotago.R

    class FragmentMascot : Fragment() {
      override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view= inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mascot, container, false)
        val listview = view.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.maskot_list)
        listview.adapter = MaskotAdapter(context,activity)
        return view
      }

      private class MaskotAdapter(val context: Context, val activity: FragmentActivity): BaseAdapter() {
       // private val mContext: Context
     private val maskot_images_list = arrayListOf<Int>(R.drawable.maskot1,R.drawable.maskot2,R.drawable.maskot3,R.drawable.maskot4,R.drawable.maskot5,R.drawable.maskot6)

        override fun getCount(): Int {
          return maskot_images_list.size //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
          return "test String" //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
          return position.toLong()//To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        //renders each row
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
          val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
          val maskot_row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.maskot_list, parent, false)

     val maskot_image = maskot_row.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.maskot_image)
            maskot_image.setImageResource(maskot_images_list.get(position))
          return maskot_row
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can use GridView or Recyclerview for multiple items in a row as your need

Comment: Ok, you can use recycle view. That's latest and easier and may follow this link to learn it. [https://www.raywenderlich.com/170075/android-recyclerview-tutorial-kotlin](https://www.raywenderlich.com/170075/android-recyclerview-tutorial-kotlin)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link. I just took a look on it and it's looking helpful.

Comment: yup. keep coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to used recycler view it is latest... or other wise you used GridLayout . I provide recycler view code it is easy to maintain..

add below dependency into app level gradle file..

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
```

make adapter like ..

```
class CommentAdapter (var mList:List<Comment>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.ItemViewHolder> (){
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    var data=mList[position]
    holder?.mEtMessage?.setText(data.message)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
    var view=LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.comment_row_layout,parent,false)
    return ItemViewHolder(view)
}

class ItemViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    var mEtMessage:EditText?=null

    constructor(itemView: View?) : super(itemView){
        mEtMessage=itemView?.findViewById(R.id.crlEtMessage)
    }
}
```

}

and define recycler view layout like below..

```
        recyclerView?.layoutManager=GridLayoutManager(activity,3,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found how to solve it at last. In order to add 3 images we can change the position add images 3 times like below.

```
val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
      val badgeRow=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.badge_list, parent, false)
        var pos = position
                for (i in 0..(maskot_images_list.size / 3)-2) {
                    val maskot_image1 = badgeRow.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.left_badge)
                    maskot_image1.setImageResource(maskot_images_list.get(pos))
                    pos++

                    val maskot_image2 = badgeRow.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.center_badge)
                    maskot_image2.setImageResource(maskot_images_list.get(pos))
                    pos++

                    val maskot_image3 = badgeRow.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.right_badge)
                    maskot_image3.setImageResource(maskot_images_list.get(pos))
                    pos++
                }
```

and may be change the getCount part like below:

```
override fun getCount(): Int {
//for 3 images decrease the number of row count 3 times
              return maskot_images_list.size/3 //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
```